# How to get a user input on a MessageBox on C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, messagebox

I have an application on C++ (on Windows API) and I ask the user to approve a task using MessageBox. However, as it's a bit sensible task and nobody reads the message, I want to change it to have an input box and the user type "I agree".

Does anybody know a simple way to do that? I find DialogBoxParam() which can do it, but it's overkilling for my needs, can you think on something more simple (or a simple way to use it)?

I found [Prompting a user with an input box? [C++]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201399/prompting-a-user-with-an-input-box-c) quite similar to my question, but there is no satisfactory answer for me (using another lib is not an option).

Comment: You can't do that with `MessageBox`. You need to make your own dialog.

Comment: WinAPI is pretty barebones and is intended for you to create what you want from scratch. Also BTW, this idea is horrible from a User Expereince point of view, all it will do is piss users off.

Comment: An 'Are you sure' dialogue-box is more standard.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write your own dialog for that. The `MessageBox` and related APIs do not offer such functionality. You could use the task dialog API (introduced in Vista) to show a dialog box with a button having customised caption. That might be a little better than plain `MessageBox` with its limited set of buttons.

I'm a little cynical about what you are trying to achieve in any case. If you force the users to type *I agree* they will ignore the content of the dialog box and type what you ask them to type.

The difference in outcome between your typing dialog and a standard button press dialog is that the user will take longer to get past the dialog, and will dislike your software, but the still not have read the content of the dialog. In other words, the only thing you will achieve by doing this is to hold up the user.

At some point you have to accept that the user takes responsibility for their actions. If you give them a helpful message and they choose to ignore it, ultimately that is on them.